# Laravel Cashier -How to Modify cashier to store additional parameter in user database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Cashier along with Stripe to manage subscriptions. The user will put their credit card information when signing up and subscribes to a plan,but i also want them to put some credits into their account when they subscribing for a specific plan.

For example if a user subscribe for `Bronze` package i want to put `300 credits` (lets say) into their account once the subscription is completed successfully.
How can i do that?? any advice.

So far my subscription code is like this

**Subscription Controller**

```
// create the users subscription
        // grab the credit card token
        $ccToken = $request->input('cc_token');
        $plan = $request->input('plan');

        // create the subscription
        try {
            $user->newSubscription('main', 'plan_CWtS4yCNvo5vAj')->create($ccToken, [
                'email' => $user->email
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return back()->withErrors(['message' => 'Error creating subscription.'.$e->getMessage()]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Successfully subscribed');
```

Since user database is populated by laravel cashier itself once the subscription is done i have no idea how can i alter so. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `create()` method returns an instance of Cashier Subscribtion model of the created row, so you can collect the returned value from `create()` in a ( $subscribtion ) variable then save whatever you want on this instance :

```
$subscribtion = $user->newSubscription('main', 'plan_CWtS4yCNvo5vAj')
                     ->create($ccToken, [
                         'email' => $user->email
                     ]);
$subscribtion->credits = 300;
//some other stuff
$subscribtion->save();
```